Converting numpy arrays of coordinates of different configuration of molecules to an xyz.file efficiently
I generated sets of xyz coordinates for four atoms in two diatomic molecules' dimers. where each of Al1, F1, Al2, F2 have their coordinates x,y and z coordinates in a separate array. each array is 33177600 long meaning I have 33177600 configurations. I want to efficiently generate an xyz file that contains the coordinates of all the configurations.
I used a for loop with an ASe library atoms object to do so, but I think there might be a more computationally efficient way of doing it. I want to avoid the for loop and use NumPy, pandas, or other efficient methods for this task. Thanks!
import numpy as np
import ase
from ase import io
from ase import Atoms
atoms=[]
for i in range(5):
    atoms.append(Atoms(['Al','F','Al','F'], positions=[(x_al1[i], y_al1[i], z_al1[i]), (x_f1[i],    y_f1[i], z_f1[i]),(x_al2[i], y_al2[i], z_al2[i]),(x_f2[i], y_f2[i], z_f2[i])]))
ase.io.write(filename='tryj.xyz',images=atoms)

The output xyz file looks like this for five configurations
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc="F F F"
Al       2.57624552      -0.00195309       0.00000000
F        3.20148847       0.00277378       0.00000000
Al      -0.25834347       0.00195220      -0.00005894
F        0.36689949      -0.00277251       0.00008371
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc="F F F"
Al       2.57624552      -0.00195309       0.00000000
F        3.20148847       0.00277378       0.00000000
Al      -0.25834347       0.00188505      -0.00051102
F        0.36689949      -0.00267715       0.00072575
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc="F F F"
Al       2.57624552      -0.00195309       0.00000000
F        3.20148847       0.00277378       0.00000000
Al      -0.25834347       0.00149618      -0.00125539
F        0.36689949      -0.00212488       0.00178290
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc="F F F"
Al       2.57624552      -0.00195309       0.00000000
F        3.20148847       0.00277378       0.00000000
Al      -0.25834347       0.00058919      -0.00186210
F        0.36689949      -0.00083677       0.00264455
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc="F F F"
Al       2.57624552      -0.00195309       0.00000000
F        3.20148847       0.00277378       0.00000000
Al      -0.25834347      -0.00058919      -0.00186210
F        0.36689949       0.00083677       0.00264455



Is it this ase ?

There is no Pandas here. Why is it tagged Pandas?

ase.io.write really does accept an Atoms or list of Atoms. So it's guaranteed to be slow. Do you need this exact output format, or can you replace everything with Pandas instead?

Yes, It is ase. I tagged Pandas because I thought Pandas could be used to resolve the problem.  ase.io.write generated the output above for me.


Select proper data structures for this task.
You can use Numpy.array():

import numpy as np

SEP = """4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
"""
keys = ['x_al1', 'y_al1', 'z_al1', 'x_f1', 'y_f1', 'z_f1',
        'x_al2', 'y_al2', 'z_al2', 'x_f2', 'y_f2', 'z_f2']

num, coords = 100, {}
for key in keys:
    np.random.seed(hash(key) % 10 + 1)
    coords[key] = np.random.rand(num) * 10

arr = np.zeros((num, 12))
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    arr[:, i] = coords[key]

# print(arr)
types = np.array(["Al", "F", "Al", "F"])


s = "{:2s} {:15.8f} {:15.8f} {:15.8f}\n"
res = []
for i in range(num):
    res.append(SEP)
    for j in range(4):
        res.append(s.format(types[j], arr[i, j * 3], arr[i, j * 3 + 1], arr[i, j * 3 + 2]))

with open('tryj.xyz', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(res)

print(res)


Prints
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      2.21993171      0.10374154      4.17022005
F       8.73429403      4.35994902      8.92860151
Al      8.73429403      8.73429403      0.76308289
F       5.50797903      4.17022005      8.73429403
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      8.70732306      5.01874592      7.20324493
F       9.68540663      0.25926232      3.31979805
Al      9.68540663      9.68540663      7.79918792
F       7.08147823      7.20324493      9.68540663
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      2.06719155      4.95773293      0.00114375
F       8.69194540      5.49662478      8.21229123
Al      8.69194540      8.69194540      4.38409231
F       2.90904739      0.00114375      8.69194540
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      9.18610908      1.33829529      3.02332573
F       5.30855692      4.35322393      0.41696626
Al      5.30855692      5.30855692      7.23465178
F       5.10827605      3.02332573      5.30855692
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      4.88411189      1.42111085      1.46755891
F       2.32728328      4.20367802      1.07656680
Al      2.32728328      2.32728328      9.77989512
F       8.92946954      1.46755891      2.32728328
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      6.11743863      2.18558676      0.92338595
F       0.11398804      3.30334821      5.95052064
Al      0.11398804      0.11398804      5.38495870
F       8.96293089      0.92338595      0.11398804
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      7.65907856      4.18508181      1.86260211
F       4.30468818      2.04648634      5.29817362
Al      4.30468818      4.30468818      5.01120464
F       1.25585310      1.86260211      4.30468818
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      5.18417988      2.48101168      3.45560727
F       4.02351360      6.19270966      4.18807429
Al      4.02351360      4.02351360      0.72051133
F       2.07242878      3.45560727      4.02351360
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      2.96800502      0.84059651      3.96767474
F       5.22674671      2.99654674      3.35407849
Al      5.22674671      5.22674671      2.68438980
F       0.51467203      3.96767474      5.22674671
4
Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3 pbc='F F F'
Al      1.87721229      3.45498640      5.38816734
F       4.78391796      2.66827275      6.22519432
Al      4.78391796      4.78391796      4.99882501
F       4.40809844      5.38816734      4.78391796
...



Note:

The repetitive header is unnecessary.
Also, the first column does not seem be necessary.
Make sure to save it with the precision that you want.


Thank you very much. The repetitive header and the first column are necessary for other parts of the code and software that will handle the file afterward.
